# Presence/absence of bottom-padding changes inner box size on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Once again I am reminded why I hate GUI programming.

I've boiled the problem I'm seeing down to this very simple HTML test case:

```
<div style="padding:5px;background-color:#ccccff">
  <form>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="username" type="password" />
    <button type="button" id="logout">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I enter it into jsfiddle's HTML area, it renders as I would expect, with nice, consistent padding all the way around (the light grey behind the purple is jsfiddle's default bakground):

[image: on-jsfiddle]

But when I put that *exact* content -- no more, no less -- into a `.html` file in the document root of a server on my laptop, and then load the page, it renders like this:

[image: on-my-mac]

*What's that extra chunk of `<div>` doing below my labels and controls? And why the difference?*

(Both examples were rendered in the same instance of Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit), running on a MacBook Pro, OS X 10.8.5.)

For the first example (served by jsfiddle), Chrome's box-visualizer widget looks like this:

[image: 19-high]

For the second example (served off my machine), the box-visualizer shows this:

[image: 35-high]

but if I subsequently *remove* the padding property from that second example, the height of the inner box drops back to `19px`.

Whatever is going on, it seems to be related specifically to *bottom* padding, because:

- even if I change the padding property to `"padding:5px 5px 1px 5px"`, the inner box is shown to be `35px` high.
- but if I change the padding property to `"padding:5px 5px 0px 5px"`, the inner box height reverts to `19px`.

I have no clue where I should start looking to debug this.

(BTW, I've already tried both `border-box` and `content-box` for `box-sizing`, but neither choice seemed to change the behavior I'm observing, in either place.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a bottom margin on the `form` element. This bottom margin appears only in [quirks mode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html#form-margin), which is being used to render your page since there is no DOCTYPE accompanying your HTML fragment.

The `div` element is unaffected, but [its padding does prevent that bottom margin from collapsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), which is why you can see it only when the padding is there. Removing the padding allows it to collapse out of the `div`, so you don't see the portion of the `div` background that it would have otherwise occupied.

Since `box-sizing` has no effect on margins, changing it on any of the elements won't have any effect.

In general, any time you are working with HTML (and CSS), the very first thing you have to make sure is that a valid DOCTYPE is present that will trigger standards mode. In HTML5, it's `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: "In general, any time you are working with HTML (and CSS), the very first thing you have to make sure is that a valid DOCTYPE is present..." Adding this to my "words to live by" file.